# Запутался, проблема с wait в Bash скрипте

Tags: bash, shell, background

Этот скрипт работает нормально:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 9 &
wait
echo "ok"
```

Выводит "ОК" через ~ 9 секунд

А вот этот:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "1" | while read in
do
sleep 9 &
done
wait
echo "ok"
```

выводит "ОК" сразу, вопрос чего я не понимаю, почему не ждем фоновый процесс?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13726764/4827341 // резюме: не используйте subshell. варианты приведены по ссылкам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что элементы конвейера `bash`, как и большинство других оболочек, запускает в дочерней *подоболочке* (*subshell*). т.е. второй пример будет аналогичен следующему:

```
(sleep 9 &); wait
```

Само собой, `wait` из родительского процесса не видит детей запущенных в дочернем процессе и поэтому сразу завершается.

В данном случае можно перенести ожидание в подоболочку:

```
echo 9 | { while read n; do
        sleep $n
    done
    wait
}
```

Или использовать перенаправление вывода процесса (*process substitution*):

```
while read n; do
    sleep $n
done < <(echo 9) # осторожно, bash'изм
wait
```

---

Другие классические способы обхода описаны в [BashFAQ/024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: Спасибо process substitution то что было нужно.